# Is it possible to tag user profile

Tags: discussion, tags

There already exist tags for question. Is it possible to create tags for users profile? (with say less than 5 tag) ? this could help us to be able to characterize the community and create appropriate incentives...

I guess this goes a bit to far but I would like to have your feelings on that point.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Nice idea; still you should go to meta.stackoverflow.com with it. On the other hand those tag-badges have similar function, but they are very hard to earn.

Comment: @csgillespie: I have tryed to improve presentation. Is it better now ?

Comment: Yes, the penny has dropped. I like the idea.

Comment: I have been to meta.stackoverflow and the question already exists.... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56065/add-tags-to-the-user-profile